# python import not recognized of my internal script

Tags: python, pyqt5, python-poetry

I have a pyqt app that runs scripts dynamically.
I execute those scripts by using

```
subprocess.Popen(['python', 'script1.py', 'arg1'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
```

I am able to reach `script1.py` but I am getting the error:

```
  from utils import file_utils\r\nModuleNotFoundError: No module named \'utils\'\r\n'
```

This is the import from the file being run dynamically:

```
sys.path.append(os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '../../utils')))
from utils import file_utils
```

`file_utls.py` is just a script. Not a module or class or anything.

When I run the app direcrly using python interpreter, everything looks good.
However, I run it after using

```
pyinstaller --onefile pyqt.pyw -i pyqt.ico
```

and clicking on the exe file being created.
It is worth mentioning that when I am not using that import, such as with other scripts, everything runs smoothly.
Google Bard suggested I should use absolute path or use `os.path`, like I have,
So, how can I resolve that import?

Edit:
directory structure:

- folder-root
- pyqtWindowApp.py - the main app that loads the script

  - actionables

    - python

      - file_to_run.py
  - utils

    - file_utils.py

Also i have added prints to the paths of the file to be executed

```
if getattr(sys, 'frozen', False):
    application_path = os.path.dirname(sys.executable)
    print('frozen')
    print (application_path)
else:
    application_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
    print ('not frozen')
    print(application_path)

sys.path.append(os.path.join(application_path, '../../utils'))
import file_utils
```

This prints:

path-to-project\actionables\python

Update:

I've reduced the problem to an issue with poetry.

When I run this app using my PyCharm, everything works smoothly.
When I run it from inside poetry shell, the same error happens.

I've added the following in `pyproject.toml`

Notice: '`utils`' folder has changed to '`python_utils`'

```
[tool.poetry.scripts]
scripts = [
    'python_utils\file_utils.py'
]
```

when I run poetry install I get
The Poetry configuration is invalid:

- [scripts.scripts] ['python_utils\file_utils.py'] is not valid under any of the given schemas

Comment: can you list the directory of your script I mean the location of your `file_utils` and parent directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `python_utils` module is not a 3rd party, thus it's not included in the `site-packages` directory, which is why the python interpreter can't locate it.

In order to add your files, you should add your codebase to the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable using the optional `env` argument of the `Popen` function:

```
new_env = os.environ
new_env['PYTHONPATH'] = new_env.get('PYTHONPATH','') + ";" + os.getcwd() # assuming you set your working directory to the codebase
subprocess.Popen(['python', 'script1.py', 'arg1'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, env=new_env)
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to add a `__init__.py` file in `utils` directory, so that python will recognize the `utils` directory as package. the `__init__.py` could be empty.

According the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#regular-packages) here.

> Python defines two types of packages, regular packages and namespace
> packages. Regular packages are traditional packages as they existed in
> Python 3.2 and earlier. A regular package is typically implemented as
> a directory containing an **init**.py file. When a regular package is
> imported, this **init**.py file is implicitly executed, and the
> objects it defines are bound to names in the package’s namespace. The
> **init**.py file can contain the same Python code that any other module can contain, and Python will add some additional attributes to
> the module when it is imported.

Comment: Thanks. I have tried that before and now again, and it doesn't help. This looks like something related to loading classes, not scripts. Am I wrong?

Comment: I still don't understand why you are trying to load the `file_utils.py` file into your code ... if you want to import functions from that file, the only thing is to  do add the `__init__.py` file then  import the functions... there is no need for that line `sys.path.append(os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '../../utils')))`

Comment: did you get the same message when you added the `__init__.py` file?

Comment: Yep. I've done as you suggested and I am still facing this issue.

Answer (score 0):

you are appending the directory path of `utils` to your `sys.path`, but you will have a problem when you run the program as an executable file because `os.path.dirname(__file__)` doesn't return the expected directory path in a `PyInstaller` environment.

lets try to use `os.path.dirname(sys.executable)` instead.

```
import sys
import os

if getattr(sys, 'frozen', False):
    application_path = os.path.dirname(sys.executable)
else:
    application_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

sys.path.append(os.path.join(application_path, '../../utils'))

from utils import file_utils
```

Comment: Thanks. I've tried that but it didn't help. Except from trying to view application_path using prints, is there anything else I could try?